Summation of a polynomial
I would like to perform a summation operation on a polynomial inside a cuda kernel which contains coefficients and function as given
y = a1*f1(x) + a2*f2(x) + a3*f3(x) + a4*f4(x);

My first idea is to loop over the three terms and use switch statements
float y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (a[i] != 0) {

            switch (i) {
            case 0: y += a[i] * f1(x); break;
            case 1: y += a[i] * f2(x); break;
            case 2: y += a[i] * f3(x); break;
            case 3: y += a[i] * f4(x); break;
            }
        }
    }

The above solution seems to be very basic and slow when number of terms in equation can be greater than 30. Now, I am thinking of creating an array of functions to remove switch statement.
float y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (a[i] != 0) {
            y += a[i] * f[i](x);
        }
    }

All threads share same a[i]. The function f[i] is again another polynomial with 1 - 8 terms.
Can this be optimized?
Update 1:
I have not yet written the code just solved the polynomial. I can share some part of the polynomial here. The actual equation looks like this:
z = a1*f1(x,y) + a2*f2(x,y) + a3*f3(x,y) + a4 * f4(x,y)

x,y are the inputs that varies across the threads

coefficients a1, a2, a3, a4 are constants.

f1(x,y) = 6*x*y ;
f2(x,y) = 2*x*(4*x^2 + 4*y^2 - 3) + 16*x*y^2 ;
f3(x,y) = 10*y^2*(3*x^2 - y^2) - 2*y^2*(5*x^2 + 5*y^2 - 4) + (3*x^2 - y^2)*(5*x^2 + 5*y^2 - 4) ;
f4(x,y) = y*(60*y + 210*y*(x^2 + y^2)^2 - 240*y*(x^2 + y^2)) - 60*(x^2 + y^2)^2 + 35*(x^2 + y^2)^3 + 30*x^2 + 30*y^2 - 4 ;



You should really avoid conditional and switch when the branches can diverge between threads. GPUs are very slow in this case (they use predication to execute such branches : i.e. they execute all paths and mask some values based on the result of the condition). Because of this, it may be faster without the if(a[i] != 0). The loop should be unrolled (otherwise it will be rather slow so it is better to check). What is the type of f[i]? Executing different function in different threads is really inefficient on GPUs because this is not SIMT-friendly.

Neither approach seems to bring you any advantage over just spelling out the formula as presented. In the second case in particular you just move the lines to wherever you declare the array f. The a[i] != 0 check can only be worthwhile if a) the function f[i] is relatively expensive and b) all threads inside a warp have the same a[i]. Is that the case?

@ Jérôme Richard
fi is a function returning a float datatype with float x as input. The terms in the function are more than 30. Unrolling the loop means writing a big code.

@Home512 Yes, all threads share same a[i]. The function f[i] is again another polynomial with 1 - 8 terms.

Why bother with if (a[i] != 0) { … }? Just do the FMAD, it will be much faster than testing the value on each loop trip and if a coefficient is truly zero it makes no difference to the result mathematically

@talonmies Right. I will avoid  the condition.

Ok so as expected this is not great at all since different threads may need to call different functions. The GPU will basically call all function which is slow. With 30 functions, this is not surprising it becomes a problem. I see only 3 solutions : remapping items so consecutive threads call the same function (if possible), or try to merge all function in a unique code without much divergence (at least less than here), or just not to use a GPU but a CPU instead for that (assuming data are not on the GPU already or you can quickly move them).

@JérômeRichard There might be a misunderstanding. If different threads would get different f[i], the first implementation would not make sense. So I would assume that just x varies among threads. Happy to be corrected by OP though.

GPU compilers aggressively inline functions for a reason, so I would avoid introducing an indirection via f[i]. If you unroll the loop in the switch implementation I would guess that the compiler will create the "big code" either way and that might just be ok as long as there is no warp divergence. The only possible optimization I can think of is introducing more parallelism by assigning different warps (different threads of the same warp would indeed introduce divergence) to different terms of the polynomial. The final result then has to be accumulated in shared memory.

@paleonix Indeed. In this case, the loop is not really needed (it seems pretty convoluted to me, especially since unrolling it manually results in a simpler and possibly faster code). The condition may help then if the functions are pretty big. A more complete (+reproducible) example would help to avoid misunderstandings and check the resulting PTX (and possibly SASS) code.

@paleonix Yes, just x varies among the threads. The a[i] and f[i] are same for all threads. But each thread will call different f[i],a[i] at a given time.There might be some threads calling same function at a given time. Now I wonder if there will be a race condition on reading or function calling.

@howl For warp divergence you just care about the threads inside a warp, not all threads on the GPU, so this is fine. There are no read-after-read race conditions. But as I said before, you don't want to use function pointers on the GPU if avoidable. You may want to learn more about GPUs before optimizing because "a big code" is not really an issue in terms of performance. Exposing more parallelism might help but as long as you are already filling the GPU with work it probably doesn't.

@paleonix I get it why inline functions are used in cuda. This will eliminate the function call overhead. The large code with inlining might increase compile time but it's ok for me. So, in the end I will just go ahead with unrolling the loop. Thank you.

@howl: For functions like those in your question, you would be far better off combining them into a single function which calculates all the four results. There are so many common terms that could be re-used (either explicitly by you or implicitly by compiler optimization) which should reduce the number of redundant calculations significantly

Looking at your first few sample functions my first reaction is that what you actually want to do is compute the polynomial in x coefficients once for each problem outside of the Cuda code entirely and hand Cuda a clean set of numerical polynomial coefficients to evaluate. Effectively turning the whole thing inside out.
Basically instead of an array of functions which will be clumsy to call and glacially slow due to conditionals inside the loop you have a 2D table of function coefficients of the various 30 polynomials as functions of y and then combine them with the weights a[i] into the working set of coefficients for Cuda to evaluate.
It may help to compute these coefficients in double precision and only round down to floats for handover to Cuda. I have concerns that the float mantissa may not be sufficient precision for your needs if |x| >> 1.
A word of caution. Float precision may not be sufficient to compute your function if there are terms that cancel and omnimously big coefficients of higher powers of x (and y) present. You might want to test that float evaluation is useful first before investing time in making the code Cuda friendly.
If I have understood your statement of the problem you ultimately have a polynomial in x to evaluate for many x (beware radius of convergence). That polynomial P(x) depends on fixed? a[n] and another variable y.
You state that the first 4 such polynomials are:
f1(x,y) = 6*x*y ;
f2(x,y) = 2*x*(4*x^2 + 4*y^2 - 3) + 16*x*y^2 ;
f3(x,y) = 10*y^2*(3*x^2 - y^2) - 2*y^2*(5*x^2 + 5*y^2 - 4) + (3*x^2 - y^2)*(5*x^2 + 5*y^2 - 4) ;
f4(x,y) = y*(60*y + 210*y*(x^2 + y^2)^2 - 240*y*(x^2 + y^2)) - 60*(x^2 + y^2)^2 + 35*(x^2 + y^2)^3 + 30*x^2 + 30*y^2 - 4 ;

These need simplifying algebraically to their canonical forms (unless there is  a specific reason why terms have to be evaluated like that which I can't see). Optimising compilers won't alter the stated bracketing order of evaluation (unless you enable unsafe fastmath optimisations which is risky).
In canonical form the f2, f3, f4 become Taylor series in x as follows (from Maxima):
f2(x) = 2*x*(12*y^2-3+4*x^2)
f3(x) = 12*y^2-25*y^4+(30*y^2-12)*x^2+15*x^4
f4(x) = -4+90*y^2-300*y^4+245*y^6+(525*y^4-360*y^2+30)*x^2+(315*y^2-60)*x^4+35*x^6

Basically what I suggest is that you compute the coefficients of the whole function term by term for a given y into an array of coefficients. I'll sketch it out with these terms as an example and coefficients a1, a2, a3, a4.
// fn[] = { 1, x, x^2, x^3,x^4,... polynomial coeffs in powers of x
   f1[] = { 0, 6*y, 0, 0, ... };
   f2[] = { 0, 24*y^2-3, 0, 4, ...};
   f3[] = { y^2*(12-25*y^2), 0, 30*y^2-12, 0, 15, ... };
   f4[] = { -4+90*y^2-300*y^4+245*y^6, 0, 525*y^4-360*y^2+30, 0, 315*y^2-60, 0, 35, 0, ...}

for (int i = 0; i< NPOLY; i++)
   mypoly[i] = a1*f1[i]+a2*f2[i]+a3*f3[i]+a4*f4[i];

There may be other go faster tweaks you can do if odd terms only occur occasionally in the low orders and the majority are predominantly odd or even functions. IOW rather than evaluate P(x) with every alternate term zero compute P'(x*x). It may even be worth splitting it into those with mixed terms, pure odd and pure even functions grouping like with like. Do check that precision obtained meets your requirements though!

Shouldn't it be something along the lines of powx*= x; mypoly[i] = (a1*f1[i]+a2*f2[i]+a3*f3[i]+a4*f4[i])*powx;? How would this handle y also varying among threads? And f2[3] should be 8 not 4.

This is the precursor step of making a set of pre weighted polynomial coefficients for a fixed y ready for Cuda to evaluate. The second phase for each value of x is done in the threads loop on sum = sum*x + mypoly[i--] or whatever fancy vectorised polynomial evaluation the hardware offers.  You will need to compute a separate set of these custom coefficients for each value of y. I note that the OP has used y in two different places with different meanings so it is a bit ambiguous what he wants.

Yeah, I also noted the ambiguous nature. I operate under the assumption that the y from y = f(x) has nothing to do with the y in f(x, y) and that x in the original post was just a shorthand/simplification for the tuple (x, y). @howl really needs to specify the number of different x and y that are needed. As this is supposed to run on a GPU I fear there will be a lot of both (i.e. it's a 2D space and not 1D space with an additional parameter).

@MartinBrown Thanks. I will further simplify my equation and provide clean code to CUDA. But is there  a difference in providing the code as you mentioned in arrays  or just shorten the equation by avoiding repetitions like x^2 + y^2 = r2. and just write 30 lines of readable code where every line shows one polynomial.

@paleonix I understand the ambiguous nature but your assumption is right as to why I did that. I am trying to model a complex 2D surface . My ray tracer provides hitpoints(x,y) on the surface and I use the polynomials to generate a new ray direction. As I am also performing  monte-carlo integration, you can imagine the samples I would need for convergence. I hope the floating precision doesn't become an issue.

There is a huge difference if you can make it into a polynomial in a single variable and compute a stripe at a time. I presume by complex surface here you mean in shape z(x,y). You really need to think hard about the magnitudes of x and y to determine if you can actually get away with using floats. My instinct is that x^6 & y^6 and worse products of those two will get you into a regime where the relative accuracy will be around 1e-4 at awkward places where big magnitude terms with opposing signs cancel.

Lucky for you it is very easy to measure performance on the GPU
const auto StartTime = clock64();
... do stuff
const auto EndTime = clock64();
const auto Diff = int(EndTime - StartTime);
if (threadIdx.x == 0) { printf("time = %i clockcycles\n", Diff); }

Some tips: avoid branches and avoid if statements. It is much faster to execute all the code unconditionally, because an if statement is translated to the following pseudo code:
if x then do_y() else do_z()
->
p = bool(x)
p? y()
p? more y()  //a handful number of statements will be predicated
!p? z()
!p? more z() 

If you have many statements in the if, a call will be made, calls are very expensive!
If you are able to translate the function f into an array whose values can be looked up, you and alter the code like so.
Your code can be efficiently executed like so:
__shared__ float y[1024]; //assume we have 1024 threads in a block.
__shared__ float f[4];
__shared__ float result[32];
//initialize f and y
//this looks like a loop, but can be optimized away if count == blockDim.x
for (int i = threadIdx.x; i < count; i += blockDim.x) {
    j = i % 4; //deduce the `f` you need
    y[i] += a[i] * f[j]; //no if/switches needed
    //more calculations, do not use ifs, but extract the data needed
    //from a shared array, so you +0, or *1 if you want to skip items.       
    //do not do division, but multiply by a (pre-calculated) 1/x 
}
//reduce 32 values into 1
const auto reduce = [&](float y1)-> float{
  y1 += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, y1, 1);
  y1 += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, y1, 2);
  y1 += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, y1, 4);
  y1 += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, y1, 8);
  y1 += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, y1, 16);
  return y1;
}
const auto y1 = reduce(y[threadIdx.x]);
//if is fine here, because conditional assignment is the exception to
//the `do-not-use-ifs` rule.
//the optimizer will lift `threadIdx.x / 32` out of the if statement.
if (threadIdx.x & 31 == 0) { result[threadIdx.x / 32] = y1; }
__syncthreads();
const auto final_result = reduce(result[threadIdx.x]);
if (threadIdx.x == 0) { globalresult[0] = final_result; }

It is hard to advise you further without knowing the exact form of functions f_i

You got rid of f being function calls. Your parallelization of these function calls causes warp divergence.

@paleonix, f should not be a function-call, it should be a lookup in some precalculated array.

Possibly but that wasn't mentioned in your answer. And according to OP there are ~30 different f()s, i.e. 30 different LUTs. Without an MRE from OP it is hard to say if this is applicable.

Thanks for highlighting the oversight, I've updated the answer

@Johan I have added the actual function to the initial post above. I am not sure if I can convert it to LUT.
